# How do I represent a packed Delphi record with Python ctypes?

Tags: python, delphi, record, ctypes

I want to know if it is possible to handle Delphi Packed records with ctypes.
I have a dll written in Delphi that is exposing some methods with stdcall convention.

On of the methods is returning a custom record packed like this:

```pascal
TMapCell = packed record
    Tile : Word;
    Z : Shortint;
end;
```

When records aren't packed I could handle them in a way like this:

```py
class TMapCell(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('Tile', c_ushort),
        ('Z', c_byte),
    ]
```

but when I am trying to use it I have an access violation erron

```
WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000112D
```

Comment: By the way, the documentation for ctypes is, just like the rest of the standard Python libraries, excellent. You can find out almost everything you ever need to know about ctypes by starting here: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the [`_pack_`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure._pack_) attribute to control packing:

```
class TMapCell(Structure):

    _pack_ = 1

    _fields_ = [
        ('Tile', c_ushort),
        ('Z', c_byte),
    ]
```

Of course, it would be so much better if you refrained from packing your records in the first place. Always prefer aligned records.

Comment: This answers your question, but may not solve your AV. The layout of the record in the question is the same for packed and aligned. Although there is a size difference. The packed record has size 3, the aligned has size 4. Anyway, it's plausible that your AV is caused by some other error.

Comment: I have no control over the dll, so I have to take what they give me. I read the standar documentation and tried with `_pack_ = 1` before asking here, but I still get AV error with it.

Comment: Well, like I said, your problem is probably elsewhere. This is the answer to the question you asked. It's just that the packing is likely not the cause of your problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan as you said, problem was elsewhere. Thank you.